# Make file dependency section, required to have x.h: y.h?

Tags: c, header, makefile, dependencies

In the following (cut down) make file, the dependencies are at the bottom. This is part of an actual make file that i am writing. In the real case there is a header file dependent on another header.

I haven't been able to find the answer elsewhere so... would i need to include a line at the bottom under dependencies to the effect of "swap.h: other.h"?

```
SRC =       swap.c other.c etc
OBJ =       swap.o other.o etc
EXE =       swap

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $(OBJ) -lm

## Dependencies

swap.o: swap.h other.h
other.o:    other.h
```

Thanks!

Comment: .h files don't get compiled.  What do you intend to achieve by calling a header a target?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there nothing to do for `swap.h` if `other.h` changes even if the first `#include`s the seconds, the short answer is no.

... But, if some C source includes `swap.h` and swap.h includes `other.h`, a change in other.h will affect /the object needed to be generated from the said C source.

Typically, however, you don't want to maintain your header dependency manually. It is laborious and error prone.

There are several ways for generating these dependencies automatically.

I can recommend the [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html) paper. This method is not perfect, but it is as good as you can get with Makefiles.

Comment: So.. if i have maintained it manually (small project) then technically i should include it.

Comment: If by 'it' you want to say `## Dependencies` (not the `swap.h: other.h` bit), then the answer is - yes. You should always ask yourself: if this file changes what else need to change? Then be very explicit about it, so `make` will know it too.

Comment: 1. "affect", not "effect". 2. Many Makefile generators handle dependency computation for you (automake and CMake for certain, probably others).

Comment: @Jack Kelly, fixed spelling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to define dependencies between header files:

```
swap.h: other.h
    touch $@
```

If `other.h` is modified, any target which depends on `swap.h` will get updated.